# Problems with search & replace by using substr_replace

Tags: php, string, search, replace

I have tried many ways, some work partially, some don't work at all. This one doesn't work at all because of the while condition which returns false all the time for some reason, it doesn't starts replacing.
What I basically want is I put into a string, then I search for a word and replace it with a different word. I managed to do that to the point that the only problem was not replacing the word if it was starting on the 0th position on the string, it was still echoing the 0th letter from the string and continued it with the new word. E.g. : "old is old" and I want to replace old with new, it would echo "onew is new".
Please tell me if I should have done anything differently as well, in order to have a more clean and perfectly optimized code for speeding up the website.
Thank you.

```
<?php 
$offset = 0;
if (isset($_POST['user_input']) && !empty ($_POST['user_input'])) {
    $initial_string = $_POST['user_input'];
    $string_length = strlen($initial_string);
    $new_string = $initial_string;
    if (isset($_POST['search_input']) && !empty ($_POST['search_input'])) {
        $search_input = $_POST['search_input'];
        $search_input_length = strlen($search_input);
    } else {
        echo 'Please write the string that you want to replace into the Search input'.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['replace_input']) && !empty ($_POST['replace_input'])) {
        $replace_input = $_POST['replace_input'];
        $replace_input_length = strlen($replace_input);
    } else {
        echo 'Please write the string that you want to switch to into the Replace input'.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    while (strpos($new_string,$search_input,$offset) === true) {
    $strpos = strpos($new_string,$search_input,$offset);
    if ($offset<$string_length) {
            $new_string = substr_replace($new_string,$replace_input,$strpos,$search_input_length);
            $offset = $offset + $replace_input_length;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $new_string;

?>

<hr>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="user_input" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><Br>
    Search: <input type="value" name="search_input"><br>
    Replace: <input type="value" name="replace_input"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code. These are some important things to take care of:

- `isset($var) && !empty($var)` is redundant. `empty($var)` also checks if the variable is set and returns true if it is not. Just `!empty($var)` will suffice.
- You're checking if `strpos()` returns the boolean value `true`. `strpos()` never returns `true`. It either returns the position of the needle in the haystack, or `false` if the needle was not found in the haystack.

### Fixing your current code

Change the `while` condition to check if `strpos()` returns a non-false value (which is the case when a match *is* found):

```
while (strpos($new_string, $search_input, $offset) !== false)
{
    $strpos = strpos($new_string, $search_input, $offset);
    if ($offset < $string_length)
    {
        $new_string = substr_replace($new_string, $replace_input, $strpos, $search_input_length);
        $offset     = $offset + $replace_input_length;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

This should correctly output:

```
new is new
```

[**Working demo**](https://eval.in/155204)

### A better solution

Your current code seems unnecessarily complicated. Essentially, you're just trying to replace *all* the occurrences of a substring in a string. This is exactly what `str_replace()` does. Use that function instead. Your code can then be simplified to just:

```
if (validation goes here) {
    $new_string = str_replace($search_input, $replace_input, $new_string);
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand all my mistakes but one. What is the difference and in which cases should I use substr_replace and in which ones str_replace?

Comment: @Maniak: For replacing text inside a specific portion, use `substr_replace()`. For everything else, use `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to replace all the occurrences of a given substring (inside a larger string) with another substring.

In order to do that you can simply use `str_replace`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Replace the `while` loop with

```
$new_string = str_replace( $search_input, $replace_input, $initial_string );
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that i don't i don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, but it seems a little over-complicated.  Why not just run a single str_replace over the whole user_input?

```
if (!empty($_POST['user_input'] && !empty ($_POST['search_input'] && !empty ($_POST['replace_input'])) {
    $str = str_replace($_POST['search_input'], $_POST['replace_input'], $_POST['user_input']);
    die(var_dump($str));
} else {
    die('error');
}
```